# Woocommerce Single product page hooks

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

How to Display a paragraph from Description section above Single Product image?

I did try using hooks but still no success

Comment: I did found some soulutions on google search, but none of them worked.

Comment: You can follow this [article](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-single-product-page/) that visually shows all the hooks for a product detail page.

Answer (score 9):

In your theme's functions.php add the code,

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary' , 'show_custom_text', 5 );

function show_custom_text() {
  global $product;
  echo '<div class="woocommerce-product-gallery" style="background: #fdfd5a; padding: 1em 2em">';
  echo $product->description;
  echo '</div>';
}
```